# Does parse pfuser currentuser perform a query to access the currently logged in user?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfuser

Does parse in objective c perform a query to get the currently logged in user?
[PFUser currentUser]
I call it from several view controllers.
Should I only do it once for the whole app?

Answer (score 1):

No, it retrieves the locally saved currently logged in user. The [docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html#/c:objc(cs)PFUser(cm)currentUser) state:

> Gets the currently logged in user from disk and returns an instance of it.

In their [guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-current-user) they mention

> Whenever you use any signup or login methods, the user is cached on disk. You can treat this cache as a session, and automatically assume the user is logged in

Answer (score 0):

No it won't it's fine, it's a singleton.

Comment: *what* is a singleton?